# Yeoman installation is showing errors

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I am unable to install yo from npm I have found these errors while running installation of yo, I have made all the paths for environment variables, but still getting error, i have also cleared the cache and re-install the nodejs , reboot my pc but still getting this error

$ npm install --global yo
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\yo -> C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\yo-complete -> C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\completion\index.js

> spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\spawn-sync
>   node postinstall

npm@1.0.0 C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: spawn-sync@1.0.15 (node_modules\yo\node_modules\spawn-sync):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall: `node postinstall`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status -4058
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "--global" "yo"
npm ERR! node v6.9.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! file ;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
npm ERR! path ;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn ;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd

npm ERR! spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall: `node postinstall`
npm ERR! spawn ;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall script 'node postinstall'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the spawn-sync package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node postinstall
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs spawn-sync
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls spawn-sync
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm@1.0.0 C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: spawn-sync@1.0.15 (node_modules\yo\node_modules\spawn-sync):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall: `node postinstall`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status -4058
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "--global" "yo"
npm ERR! node v6.9.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9

npm ERR! Callback called more than once.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1

Please tell me what is the problem with it.

Comment: IS there anyone who can answer this issue

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me too... in recent distributions many packages install nodejs as the node.js executable, while spawn-sync attempts to call node, that is why this fails.

As a workaround, you can create a softlink from node to nodejs. Something like:

```
sudo ln -s `which nodejs` /usr/bin/node
```

Answer (score 0):

Just install the latest version of nodejs and the error will get resolved.
Type the instructions in the terminal and node js will get updated:

1. `$ sudo apt purge nodejs` (for removing previous files of node js)
2. `$ wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo bash` -(it will download latest version of node)
3. `$ sudo apt-get install nodejs`

and it is done.